# Json Request in node js

Tags: node.js, json, express, request, response

I tried this code in node js:

```
const express = require('express');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(express.json())


 app.post("/Picture", (req, res, next) => {


        if(req.body == { aaa: 'aaa'}){

            res.send(body)
            console.log("well done!!!!")
           

        }


      
    })
```

I want when user enter in body this json object { aaa: 'aaa'} then get response but this code not work I dont know how i can make user can only send specific json objects

Comment: For such a scenario, it's better to declare some DTOs. Check this: [https://github.com/typestack/class-validator] (class-validator)

Comment: It would be helpful if you would tell us what the `req.body` variable contains when receiving a request.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to check that the body contains a property "aaa" with the string "aaa"?

```js
if (typeof req.body === "object" && req.body != null && req.body.aaa === "aaa") {
    res.send(body)
    console.log("well done!!!!")
}
```

Comparing an object to another object with `obj == { ... }` does **not** check if the two objects are of the same structure but instead check if they are the same object instance!

Edit: Maybe this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects) helps

Comment: I tried your code and I wrote in body in postman {"aaa":"aaa"} but also not working

Comment: Can you print the body you receive with `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: It just keeps running without any response but when i remove this if Condition he work good and give response